# Change size of stored video using video writer?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to store video after processing it with reduced size.Currently i am using the same size as the input video.I am working on open CV with c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aim to change video resolution then use `resize()` function to a matrix that stores your image:

```
Mat source, destination;
IplImage new_img;
int fps = 30;

// Apply resize
resize(source, destination, Size(640, 360), 1, 1, 1);

// Create writer
CvVideoWriter *new_writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("video.mp4",CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2'), fps, destination.size(), 3);

new_img = destination.operator IplImage();  
// 1-if image written or 0 if failed
int ret = cvWriteFrame(new_writer, (const IplImage*)&new_img);
printf("Written?: %d\n", ret);

// And finally release writer
cvReleaseVideoWriter(&new_writer);
```

If you aim to reduce video size on a disk then try to create VideoWriter with various codecs such as:

```
CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')    = MPEG-1 codec

CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')    = motion-jpeg codec (does not work well)

CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2') = MPEG-4.2 codec

CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3') = MPEG-4.3 codec

CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X') = MPEG-4 codec

CV_FOURCC('U', '2', '6', '3') = H263 codec

CV_FOURCC('I', '2', '6', '3') = H263I codec

CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1') = FLV1 codec
```